# PHP PDO Multiple update query inserts garbage into the table

Tags: php, json, insert, pdo

I am receiving a JSON object from my client side, which contains the attributes of a location in a random order.

Almost each component of the address can be either followed, or preceded by the other.
For example: the state may come before or after the, country, and the city may be anywhere in between.

So I've created a function, that dynamically binds the each parameter to the place where it belongs.
But for some reason, the only thing that I get in my DB, is garbage positive and negative integers.

simple debugging, by echo - ing the generated queries and the bound values didn't help much.

Here is the output for example(First the query, then the bound params in the following form:
 :param --- value) :

```
    [1]UPDATE locations SET active = :active,locality = :locality,local_area = :local_area,state = :state,state_short = :state_short,country_full = :country_full,country_short = :country_short,postal_code = :postal_code,ya = :ya,za = :za WHERE location_id = 385
    Params:
    :active --- true:locality --- Moscow:local_area --- gorod Moskva:state --- Moscow
    :state_short --- Moscow:country_full --- Russia:country_short --- RU:postal_code --- 121069:ya --- 55.7427928:za --- 37.61540089999994

    [2]UPDATE locations SET active = :active,street_number = :street_number,route = :route,locality = :locality,sub_local_area = :sub_local_area,local_area = :local_area,state = :state,state_short = :state_short,country_full = :country_full,country_short = :country_short,ya = :ya,za = :za WHERE location_id = 386+++:active --- true:street_number --- 31:route --- Glategny Esplanade:locality --- St Peter Port:sub_local_area --- St Peter Port:local_area --- Guernsey:state --- Bailiwick of Guernsey:state_short --- Bailiwick of Guernsey:country_full --- Grosney:country_short --- GG:ya --- 49.461137:za

 --- -2.5333570000000236
```

Code:

```
function updateMultipile($table, $data = array()){

    $update_query = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        $sql = "UPDATE $table SET ";
            foreach($value as $column => $updatedValue){
                $sql .= $column . " = :" . $column . ",";
            }
            $sql = rtrim($sql, ", ");

        $sql .= " WHERE location_id = " . intval($key); 
        $update_query[$i] = $sql;
        $i++;
    }

    try{
        $conn = DBLink::getInstance();
        $j = 0;
        $success = 0;
        foreach($data as $fieldset => $value){
            echo('[1]');
            $sth = $conn->prepare($update_query[$j]);
            echo $update_query[$j] . "+++";
            foreach($value as $key => $myValue){
                $myKey = ':' . $key;
                $sth->bindValue($myKey, $myValue); //PDO::PARAM_STR);
                echo($myKey . " --- " . $myValue);
            }   
            if($sth->execute()){
                $success++;
            }
            else{
                echo $sth->errorCode();
            }

            $j++;
        }   
    }
    catch(PDOException $err){
        echo $err::getMessage;
    }   

    return $success;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

<s>Mysql do not support multiple updates nor multiple queries (my default).

you need to run these updates separately</s>
I see now you're running them separately already. You know it's hard to run a code using your head, not computer.

Apart from your problem with this code, why not to use some database wrapper? To make the code as simple as

```
function updateMultipile($table, $data = array())
{
    $db = DBLink::getInstance();
    foreach($data as $id => $update)
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE ?n SET ?u WHERE location_id = ?i";
        $db->query($table,$update,$id); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, My function treats a 2-dimensional array, in a situation where the user choices to update more than 1 location at a time.

other than that, it's pretty much the same.

Comment: I see. It's ultimately unreadable too. And 10 times larger than it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, seems that the problem was that I was trying to execute the same statement several times, or perhaps that bindParam, doesn't work in a foreach loop when provided with a value ($myValue), I would've used $value[$myKey] instead, since this functions receives a reference and not a value.

anyway, I 've decided that for my needs in this case, bindValue is sufficient.

Works like a charm.

function updateMultipile($table, $data = array()){

```
    $update_query = array();
$i = 0;
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        $sql = "UPDATE $table SET ";
            foreach($value as $column => $updatedValue){
                $sql .= $column . " = :" . $column . ",";
            }
            $sql = rtrim($sql, ", ");

        $sql .= " WHERE location_id = " . intval($key); 
        $update_query[$i] = $sql;
        $i++;
    }

try{
    $conn = DBLink::getInstance();
    $j = 0;
    $success = 0;
    foreach($data as $fieldset => $value){
        $sth[$j] = $conn->prepare($update_query[$j]);
        foreach($value as $key => $myValue){
            $myKey = ':' . $key;
            $sth[$j]->bindValue($myKey, $myValue); //PDO::PARAM_STR);

        }   
        if($sth[$j]->execute()){
            $success++;
        }
        else{
            echo $sth[$j]->errorCode();
        }

        $j++;
    }   
}
catch(PDOException $err){
    echo $err::getMessage();
}   

return $success;
}
```